# OccupancyGrid not getting published - Python

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, so I want to publish an occupancy grid of a map.png file I have.

After running this node, I do *rostopic list* but it doesn't show me any published map. Can someone tell what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy 
import cv2 as cv
from nav_msgs.msg import *
from std_msgs.msg import *

grid = OccupancyGrid()
def load():
    img = cv.imread('map.png', 0)

    for i in range(len(img)):
        img[i] = (img[i] / 255) * 100
    
    grid.data = img
    pub.publish(grid)
    

def main():
    rospy.init_node('loadmap', anonymous = True)
    global pub
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/map', OccupancyGrid, queue_size = 10)
    load()
    rospy.spin
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340863/occupancygrid-not-getting-published---python./) by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is most likely being published, but only once, and too fast after creating the `Publisher`. This doesn't leave any time for any potential `Subscriber`s to actually notice it, register, prepare to receive the data and then actually receive it.

If you want to give "late joiners" a chance to receive the message -- and you don't publish periodically, or have messages changing contents often, you could try using a *latched* `Publisher`. From [wiki/rospy/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers: rospy.Publisher initialization](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#rospy.Publisher_initialization):

> There are additional advanced options that allow you to configure the `Publisher`:

> [..]

> - `latch=False`

> Enable 'latching' on the connection. When a connection is latched, a reference to the last message published is saved and sent to any future subscribers that connect. This is useful for slow-changing or static data like a map. The message is *not copied*! If you change the message object after publishing, the change message will be sent to future subscribers.

Note how publishing data "like a map" is given as one of the cases in which this could be useful.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-01**:
There are quite a few Q&As about publishing too fast, or not "seeing any message" here on this site. To find them, use Google with `site:answers.ros.org` and your keywords.

**Comment by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on 2020-01-01**:
That seems do it! Thanks a lot!